# How is it possible to write unit test before write source code?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

As the unit test is a white box test, it assumes that you must know in advance all the cases your code must treat, all the client objects  (aka Mock object in the test) your code must deal with, and the correct order in which client objects  must appear in the code (since unit test take in account the calling of mock object). In other words you must know exactly the detailed algorithm of your code. Before you can exactly know the algorithm of your code you must write it first!

From my point of view I don't see how it's possible to write correct unit test before writing source code. Nevertheless it's possible to write functional tests first since functional tests are sort of user requirement.
Your advice?
Best regard

**AN EXAMPLE IS GIVEN FOR THIS QUESTION:**
[How to write test code before write source code when they are objects dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538910/how-to-write-test-code-before-write-source-code-when-they-are-objects-dependenci)

Answer (score 31):

> In other word you must know exactly the detailled algorithm of your code.

Not quite.  You must know exactly the detailed *behavior* of your code, as observed from outside the code itself.  The algorithm which achieves this behavior, or combination of algorithms, or any levels of abstraction/nesting/calculations/etc. are immaterial to the tests.  The tests only care that the desired result is achieved.

The value of the tests, then, is that they are the specifications of how the code should behave.  So the code is free to change all you want, as long as it can still be validated against the tests.  You can improve performance, refactor for readability and supportability, etc.  The tests ensure that the behavior remains unchanged.

For example, suppose I want to write a function which adds two numbers.  You may know in your head how you're going to implement it, but put that knowledge aside for a moment.  You're not implementing it yet.  First, you're implementing the test...

```
public void CanAddIntegers()
{
    var addend = 1;
    var augend = 1;
    var result = MyMathObject.Add(addend, augend);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result);
}
```

Now that you have a test, you can implement the method...

```
public int Add(int addend, int augend)
{
    return ((addend * 2) + (augend * 2)) / 2;
}
```

Whoa.  Wait a minute... Why on Earth did I implement it like that?  Well, from the perspective of the test, who cares?  It passes.  The implementation meets the requirements.  And now that I have a test, I can safely refactor the code...

```
public int Add(int addend, int augend)
{
    return addend + augend;
}
```

That's a little more sane.  And the test still passes.  In fact, I can further reduce the code...

```
public int Add(int addend, int augend)
{
    return 2;
}
```

Guess what?  The test still passes.  It's the only test we have, it's the only specification given, so the code "works."  So clearly we need to improve the tests to cover more cases.  Writing more tests will give us the specifications we need to write more code.

In fact, that last implementation *should* have been the first one, according to [the third rule of TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd):

> You are not allowed to write any more production code than is sufficient to pass the one failing unit test.

So in a purely-Uncle-Bob-driven TDD world, we would have written that last implementation first, then written more tests and gradually improved the code.

This is known as the **Red, Green, Refactor** cycle.  It's very well illustrated in a simple slightly-less-contrived example, the [Bowling Game](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheBowlingGameKata).  The purpose of that exercise is to practice that cycle:

1. First, write a test which expects certain behavior.  This is the **Red** part of the cycle, because the test will fail without the behavior in place.
2. Next, write code to exhibit that behavior.  This is the **Green** part of the cycle, because its purpose is to get the test to pass.  And *only* to get the test to pass.
3. Finally, refactor the code and improve it.  This is, naturally, the **Refactor** part of the cycle.

Where you're getting stuck is that you're perpetually in the **Refactor** part of the cycle.  You're already thinking about how to make the code better.  What algorithm would be correct, how to optimize it, how it ultimately *should* be written.  To that end, TDD is an exercise in *patience*.  Don't write the best code... *yet*.

1. First, determine what the code *should* do, and *nothing more*.
2. Next, write code that *does* it, and *nothing more*.
3. Finally, improve that code and make it better.

---

**UPDATE**

I came across something which reminded me of this question, and a random though occurred to me.  Perhaps I misinterpreted the circumstances of what you're asking.  How are you managing your dependencies?  That is, what sort of dependency injection methodology are you using?  It sounds like that may be the root of the issue being discussed here.

For about as long as I can remember, I've used something like [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com) (or, more commonly, home-grown implementations of the same concept).  And in doing so I tend toward a very specific style of dependency injection.  It sounds like you're using a different style.  Constructor injection, perhaps?  I'll assume constructor injection for the sake of this answer.

So then let's say, as you indicate, that `MyMathObject` has dependencies on `MyOtherClass1` and `MyOtherClass2`.  Using constructor injection, that makes the footprint of `MyMathObject` look like this:

```
public class MyMathObject
{
    public MyMathObject(MyOtherClass1 firstDependency, MyOtherClass2 secondDependency)
    {
        // implementation details
    }

    public int Add(int addend, int augend)
    {
        // implementation details
    }
}
```

And so, as you indicate, the tests need to supply the dependencies or mocks thereof.  In the footprint of the class there's no indication of the *actual use* of `MyOtherClass1` or `MyOtherClass2`, but there is indication of the *need* for them.  As dependencies they are loudly advertised by the constructor.

So this begs the question you've asked... How can one write the tests first when one hasn't implemented the object yet?  Again, there's no indication of the *actual use* in only the external-facing design of the object.  So the dependency is an implementation detail that needs to be known.

Otherwise, you'd first write this:

```
public class MyMathObject
{
    public int Add(int addend, int augend)
    {
        // implementation details
    }
}
```

Then you'd write your tests for it, then you'd implement it and discover the dependencies, then you'd *re-write* your tests for it.  Therein lies the problem.

The problem that you've found, however, isn't an issue of the tests or of Test Driven Development.  The problem is actually in the design of the object.  Despite the fact that `// implementation details` have been glazed over, there's still an implementation detail that's escaping.  There's a *leaky abstraction*:

```
public class MyMathObject
{
    public MyMathObject(MyOtherClass1 firstDependency, MyOtherClass2 secondDependency)
    {                   ^---Right here                 ^---And here

        // implementation details
    }

    public int Add(int addend, int augend)
    {
        // implementation details
    }
}
```

The object isn't encapsulating and abstracting its implementation details sufficiently.  It's trying to, and the use of dependency injection is a major step toward that.  But it isn't fully there yet.  This is because the dependencies, which are implementation details, are *externally visible* and *externally known* by other objects.  (In this case, the testing object.)  So in order to satisfy the dependencies and make `MyMathObject` work, external objects need to know about its implementation details.  They all do.  The test object, any production code objects which use it, anything and everything that relies on it in any way.

To that end, you might want to consider switching around how the dependencies are managed.  Instead of something like constructor injection or setter injection, *further* invert the management of dependencies and have the object internally resolve them through yet another object.

Using the aforementioned service locator as a starting pattern, it's pretty easy to craft an object whose sole purpose (whose single responsibility) is to resolve dependencies.  If you're using a dependency injection framework then this object is generally just a pass-through for the framework's functionality (but abstracting the framework itself... so one less dependency, which is a good thing).  If using home-grown functionality than this object abstracts that functionality.

But what you end up with is something like this within `MyMathObject`:

```
private SomeInternalFunction()
{
    var firstDependency = ServiceLocatorObject.Resolve<MyOtherClass1>();
    // implementation details
}
```

So now the footprint of `MyMathObject`, even with dependency injection, is:

```
public class MyMathObject
{
    public int Add(int addend, int augend)
    {
        // implementation details
    }
}
```

No leaky abstractions, no externally-known dependencies.  Tests don't need to be changed as implementation details are changed.  This is another step toward de-coupling the tests from the objects they're testing.

Comment: Assume that  when i'm going to implemented class MyMathObject i must use another client class: MyOtherClass1 and MyOtherClass2. The test you have writen must declare explictly MyOtherClass1 and MyOtherClass2 as mockObject. Then test you have write first is quickly obselete

Comment: @Belin: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you referring to dependency inversion?  You can mock your dependencies, since in this case all you're testing is `MyMathObject`.  (Of course, the same tests can be used for both unit testing and integration testing if the choice between a mock and a live implementation is just a matter of configuration.  From the perspective of the test, which is outside the implementation, there is no difference in behavior.)

Comment: @Belin: Well, tests become obsolete all the time.  The Refactor part of the cycle doesn't just improve the code, it also improves the tests.  In that case it's the code which is re-validating the tests as you refactor them.  The code and the tests grow at the same pace, side-by-side.  Think of them like double-entry bookkeeping practices.

Comment: I say that if the class under the test is using other class, those other class must be mocked in the unit test. Then your test will be quickly become obsolete if in advance you don't know which other class the main class will use.

Comment: Why then write test first if after writing the code , the test must always rewrite according your code? i found that is equivalent to write test after

Comment: @Belin: Why does the unit test need to know about the dependencies?  It's not relevant to the test itself.  Perhaps the test suite as a whole needs to wire up the dependencies, if you're not otherwise using a dependency injection framework.  But the individual test shouldn't be doing that.  It should just test the behavior of the object being tested, nothing more.  Don't confuse the "arrange" part of the test with the initialization of the domain and the objects therein.  The bootstrapping of dependencies is part of that initialization.

Comment: @Belin: If you have to re-write your test after you write your code then either the test was wrong or the code is wrong.

Comment: The unit test need to know about the dependencies because, dependencies must be mocked. If dependencies are not mocked then i think  your test is not unit test, but integration or functional test, since more than one class are taken i account in the test. And is the responsibility of the unit test to mock dependencies.

Comment: @Belin: It's the responsibility of the unit test (the single method testing the one single thing) to test the behavior and to _only_ test the behavior.  It is not the responsibility of the unit test to initialize the domain and bootstrap the dependencies.  That might happen in the same unit testing project in some initialization method, perhaps even be called before each individual unit test.  But it's not in the method itself.  You're mixing responsibilities.  If the unit test "needs to know" about a dependency then it's also testing the dependency, at least in part.

Comment: In the production environment the container wire dependencies of  a class . In the unit test environment since container are not use who is responsible to give to the class under test, the object needed to achieved it's  work?

Comment: If some helper class is using in the unit test environment ( fixture class or other thing) to boostrap or initialize mocked client, then these helper class must me referenced in the unit test in think. And the unit test code will be always updated

Comment: @Belin: It sounds like you're getting to an entirely different question than what was originally asked, and one in which an illustration of how your dependencies are connected would be of use.  You might want to start a new question asking about how to manage dependencies in a test setup vs. a production setup.  Honestly, I haven't encountered what you seem to be describing because my setups have never been so different between production and test.

Comment: More. Unit test must ensure that mocked object  are calling the right number of time with the right value parameter

Comment: @David: I will asked again the same question but with some sample to illustrated correctly the problem. It's not only a boostrap or initialization problem. next time

Comment: @Belin: I came across something which reminded me of this question and I think I had some more insights that may help you.  If I'm correct, we just weren't on the same page about your dependency injection methodologies.  I've updated the answer to reflect some more information.

Comment: wow, really usefull content here, great question and an wounderful answer

Answer (score 2):

Clearly you cannot write a test if you have no understanding of what the "software" intent is, but it is absolutely possible *if* the **requirements** or **specifications** are detailed.

You can write something that fits the requirement **that will fail**; *then* produce the minimum amount of work to make the test pass based on the specification.

Unless you're some kind of genius - this first cut will need refactoring and abstractions introduced, patterns, maintainability, performance and all kinds of other things accounted for.

So if the requirements are understood, you can test first - but the test will not pass until the implementation comes together and only the implementation to make the test pass is required.

It won't always fit the bill in reality to work in this way - particularly if specification is hard to come by. You need to be careful not to blindly storm down this path if you're not getting what you need as a developer. It's also, often, impossible to achieve when inheriting code or adding to "brownfield" projects. As a developer, it's important to work out the practicalities early on.

Comment: I think test related to requirements is functional test not unit test.  It's easier to write functional

Comment: Which unit tests will you write which are not related ultimately to the functionality of the software? Unit tests are at a much lower level, but still relevant for test-first.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with: plenty of unit tests require no Mocks, no interactions with other objects; your question doesn't apply to those.

If the purpose, or part of the purpose, of a new method is to have an effect on some collaborating object, then that is part of what must be tested.  If that's not its purpose, but your implementation incidentally has an effect on a collaborator, then you should not be testing that incidental effect.

Either way, it's easy to see that you can write the test before writing the code.  If your method is supposed to affect another object, then the test should say so.  If your method isn't supposed to, the test needs to say nothing about the method's interaction with other objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really hard problem for people to get past when starting TDD.  I'm sure there are a lot of good answers on SO and especially on programmers.stackexchange.com (this question is probably more suited for that forum).

There are a lot of things I could say to help you understand, but none would work as well as you actually doing some TDD.  As a quick place to start, I'll refer you to [this article on code katas](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/05/02/kata-the-only-way-to-learn-tdd), which links to some useful TDD exercises.

Comment: My simple question is how you can know in advance the client class your class must use? in the black box test ( functional test) it's not necessary to know how my class is doing in the detail. All thing i must know is what is the final result i expect when i calling a method

Comment: @Belin, go try it.  Really.  Reading about it is not going to help you get it if David's answer didn't.

Comment: This is the example show exactly the problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538910/how-to-write-test-code-before-write-source-code-when-they-are-objects-dependenci

Answer (score 0):

Well not really. With TDD you are starting off with your test cases which you are anticipating your product code to handle. It doesnt mean there should be *no* product code. Your classes functions etc can exist. You start off with failing test cases and then keep making changes to your product code to get them to pass.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730844(v=vs.80).aspx#guidelinesfortdd_topic2

Comment: How to know in advance object client your class must use, i think you must a least write a sequence diagram an a sequence diagram is from my point of view a sort of algorithm

Comment: Well if your test needs it you will go write it. You may start off by using a class that does not exist and then generating the class and then slowly build out your logic from there.

Comment: It's not longer unit test from my point of view. Unit test must be working even if client class are not implemented yet

Comment: Your UTs are supposed to be passing when you complete the functionality that you are delivering targeted by these tests. No one said TDD wont disrupt any established understandings.

Comment: This is an example of what i talk about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538910/how-to-write-test-code-before-write-source-code-when-they-are-objects-dependenci