# How to write test code before write source code when they are objects dependencies?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I'l will take an example:
 **requirement**: construct a piece of material following these rule: 
among given < 100 => material is green
100 < among <300=> material is yellow
among > 300=> material is red

My test class:

```
        class MaterialTest{
          MaterialConstructor materialCons
          public void testBuild(){
                 materialCons.setAmount(150);
                 Material material=materialCons.build();
                 assertEqual(material.getColor(),"Yellow");
              }
    }
```

From know i don't how to implemented materialCons.build(); After design and analysis i've implemented MaterialCosntructor  as follow:

```
    public class MaterialConstructor {

         private Helper1 helper1;
         private Helper2 helper2

        MaterialConstructor (Helper1 help1, Helper2 help2){
      .................   
    }

    public Material build(Double among){
         part1=helper1.builpart(among);
        return helper2.construct(part1);
    }

}
```

In my initial test class i must includes code like this:

```
helper1=createMock(Helper1)
helper2=createMock(Helper2)

materialCons=new MaterialConstructor (helper1, helper2)

.....................

expected(helper1.builpart(150)).andReturn(some result)
expected(helper2.construct(some result)).andReturn("Yellow")
```

as result we can get this updated class test:

```
  class MaterialTest{
         MaterialConstructor materialCons
        public void testBuild(){
            helper1=createMock(Helper1)
            helper2=createMock(Helper2)
            materialCons=new MaterialConstructor (helper1, helper2)
            expected(helper1.builpart(150)).andReturn(some result)
            expected(helper2.construct(some result)).andReturn("Yellow")
             materialCons.setAmount(150);
             Material material=materialCons.build();
             assertEqual(material.getColor(),"Yellow");

          }
            }
```

hence my test code will be update after writen my source code!

This will appear many time ( since it's difficult at specification time to know which dependencies class you must use to solve your problem). Then unit-test class will be always obsolete after written source code!

Answer (score 2):

Following a strict TDD workflow such as the [3 Laws of TDD](http://agileinaflash.blogspot.fr/2009/03/unclebobs-three-rules-of-tdd.html) would definitely put an end to your hesitations.

With it you can't have such things as "After design and analysis i've implemented MaterialCosntructor ..." since you are supposed to

> Write only enough production code to pass a test

Which basically means : just return `"Yellow"` as your first implementation.

Then you would add more tests (green, red material) and incrementally design your class to handle these additional cases.

Comment: when you say "Write only enough production code to pass a test". Production code may be composed to many units code. Then those units code are not relevant for TDD, and units tests are appropriated for units code, and not for the whole production code. My remark it's that TDD is relevant only for functional or integration test.

Comment: I don't quite see what you're getting at. The important thing in the third TDD rule is not "production code", it's "**only enough** production code", which means *as few lines of code as possible*. By following this set of rules, you'll never end up with obsolete test code after writing production code, which I think was your original problem, right ?

Comment: say: "it's "only enough production code". In my example,  the code  i have writen is enough to run successfuly my unit test,. If you think is not rigth, please show  me how you can write unit-test for the case of my example , before write the source code. My opinion is that they are confusions beetween functional test, integration test and unit-test. I'll start another thread of discussion for showing cleary my vision, and explain why i think TDD is only relevant for functional or integration test

Comment: "the code i have writen is enough to run successfuly my unit test" => `public String getColor() { return "Yellow"; }` **This** is just enough to make your test pass. Of course, it will be changed as you add more tests, namely for green and red, but the important thing is, it makes the test pass, and your test code *doesn't become deprecated after you've written the production implementation*.

Comment: i don't understand your example public String getColor(){return "Yellow"} you write arbitrary code just for passing test ? or you must write code that is right and that must pass test? assume that code that i've written is the more reduced code that can be write. And tell me how you can execute sucessfully the first test classe without updated it

Answer (score 0):

No I think your idea is absolutely brilliant to have unit test cases for testing objects. I do not think the test class will be obsolete after written source code because in your case you have designed the class members and class methods.. the only thing that seems to be stopping you is to write the EasyMock testcases.. Here is some help material, maybe it will make things more clear for you [IBM Developer Works Simulation Page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-easymock/index.html) ..

There is also one more hyperlink which is by EasyMock readme themselves [EasyMock ReadMe](http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock2_2_Documentation.html)

Comment: To make a strict unit test we must use mocking else it's not longer unit test but  integration or functional test. using mocking imply  to know internal behavior of ur class under the test as  showing in my example. it's not possible to know internal behavior during specification time, then it's not possible to write usable unit-test  before writing source code

Comment: unit tests are not written during specification time. As you would know that The goal of unit testing is to isolate each part of the program and show that the individual parts are correct. A unit test provides a strict, written contract that the piece of code must satisfy.Unit testing allows the programmer to refactor code at a later date, and make sure the module still works correctly (e.g., in regression testing). The procedure is to write test cases for all functions and methods so that whenever a change causes a fault, it can be quickly identified and fixed.

Comment: Continuing on my previous comment what i meant was that if the object behaviour is going to change extensively as your software process continues it is futile or extensive work to write unit test cases for those objects because the criteria with which they were written would not be satisfied. but unit tests are definitely not written during specification time. they are written when the specification has been absorbed into a functional requirement and the functional requirement has been used to identify the behaviour of the actors of your system using OO Methodologies.

Comment: @Chanwit That's right. Therefore the unit tests must be write a least after object design. But from my opinion in the practice, object design is not necessary. After analysis i found that is more pragmatic to write directly source code. Then in that case unit test can't be write before writen source code, thus TDD is not applicable for unit testing, it's only applicable for functional or integration test

Comment: well what u r talking about is extreme programming. i can see that ur strength lies in coding but it is my request 2 u to try to do the design before directly writing source code. there are several strengths of design.. Design lets u create reusable libraries and components which can be shared across the enterprise.Apart from that when u look at the system as a whole, u will be able to decide which are the internal OO component libraries that u can/should borrow and likewise the 3rd party component libraries that you could borrow.